# Find all matching files and renaming in bash shell

Tags: bash, file, find, mv

Basically I'm adding a temporary `~` at end of my file to know I've touched them. So they look like `file.txt~`. I can always change the extension if it makes my next step easier which is renaming them to `file.txt.old`.

My approach was to do a `find directory -name '*~'` than piping to `mv`. Im just not sure how to handle the `~`.

Any pointer would be appreciated

Comment: `find <dir> -iname '*~'`? It works on my machine.

Comment: Yes I know it works but I need to remove `~` and add `.old`

Comment: Eops I'm sorry, I thought the issue was the missing `-iname` in your `find` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find -name '*~' | while read file
do 
    mv -v $file $(echo $file | sed 's@\(.*\)~@\1.old@')
done
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I forgot about `sed`. Can you explain how this works? I dont get the whole backslashes and 1s stuff. Sorry I'm new to bash shell scripting

Comment: Sure, I pipe the output from `find` to `while`. Then I consume a *line* of input with `read` into a variable named `file`. To remove the `~`, I use a sub-shell that echos `$file` into `sed`. `sed` removes the `~` by capturing what comes before `~`, using [back references](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj37aflq7ndAhWry4MKHTz0A6sQFjAAegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.regular-expressions.info%2Fbackref.html&usg=AOvVaw2fWRNLtMAjIyqrRLdfzHn5). Then, I use the captured text in the substitution, concatenating `.old`; this output is used in `mv`.

Comment: Thats awsome! Thanks for the explanation and for helping me out. Very much appreciated